# hadoop YARN performance : running the Example of wordCount on cluster is extremely slow on

Tags: performance, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Recently I set up the Hadoop cluster to test, the cluster has two nodes for tasks, and is based on Yarn.

I know that Hadoop is not suitable for the examples, it has a good performance in very large data level, but it's still too slow. I mean extremely slow. My input file is a document of 500,000 words, and reduce number is 2.

Here is the log:

```
 hadoop jar /home/hadoop/hadoopTest.jar  com.hadoop.WordCountJob /wordcountest /wordcountresult

Job started: Mon Dec 23 12:38:13 CST 2013
13/12/23 12:38:13 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.YarnClientImpl is inited.
13/12/23 12:38:14 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.YarnClientImpl is started.
13/12/23 12:38:14 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/12/23 12:38:27 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/12/23 12:38:27 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
13/12/23 12:38:27 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
13/12/23 12:38:27 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
13/12/23 12:38:27 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
13/12/23 12:38:27 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
13/12/23 12:38:27 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
13/12/23 12:38:27 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.reduce.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduce.class
13/12/23 12:38:27 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.inputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.inputformat.class
13/12/23 12:38:27 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
13/12/23 12:38:27 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
13/12/23 12:38:27 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.outputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.outputformat.class
13/12/23 12:38:27 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
13/12/23 12:38:27 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
13/12/23 12:38:27 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
13/12/23 12:38:29 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1383617275312_0021
13/12/23 12:38:30 INFO client.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1383617275312_0021 to ResourceManager at Hadoop1/111.11.11.11:8032
13/12/23 12:38:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://kmHadoop1:8088/proxy/application_1383617275312_0021/
13/12/23 12:38:30 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1383617275312_0021
13/12/23 12:43:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1383617275312_0021 running in uber mode : false
13/12/23 12:43:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/12/23 13:03:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 67% reduce 0%
13/12/23 13:03:43 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/12/23 13:07:04 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 37%
13/12/23 13:07:07 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 51%
13/12/23 13:07:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 67%
13/12/23 13:07:51 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 69%
13/12/23 13:07:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 70%
13/12/23 13:07:54 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 85%
13/12/23 13:07:54 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
13/12/23 13:07:54 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1383617275312_0021 completed successfully
13/12/23 13:07:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 43
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=519233
                FILE: Number of bytes written=1254635
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=2356520
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=427594
                HDFS: Number of read operations=9
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=4
        Job Counters 
                Launched map tasks=1
                Launched reduce tasks=2
                Data-local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=1225928
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=495508
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=8646
                Map output records=420146
                Map output bytes=4187027
                Map output materialized bytes=519225
                Input split bytes=122
                Combine input records=0
                Combine output records=0
                Reduce input groups=35430
                Reduce shuffle bytes=519225
                Reduce input records=420146
                Reduce output records=35430
                Spilled Records=840292
                Shuffled Maps =2
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=2
                GC time elapsed (ms)=263996
                CPU time spent (ms)=222750
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=529215488
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=4047876096
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=479268864
        Shuffle Errors
                BAD_ID=0
                CONNECTION=0
                IO_ERROR=0
                WRONG_LENGTH=0
                WRONG_MAP=0
                WRONG_REDUCE=0
        File Input Format Counters 
                Bytes Read=2356398
        File Output Format Counters 
                Bytes Written=427594
Job ended: Mon Dec 23 13:07:55 CST 2013
The job took 1782 seconds.
```

We can see the timestamp before each line of the log.

It seems it is slow at every step : init, check the input path, launch on the Yarn , Mapreduce, etc.

And it took 1783 seconds for the entire process.
What happened ?  Did I do something wrong ?

My hadoop version is CDH4.3.0  , 2 nodes for the cluster. And there are thousands small files in the Hdfs, Is that a problem?

Comment: Are those "thousands small files" also in your input path /wordcountest ?

Comment: No , it`s not.  the small files are in the other paths

Answer (score 0):

I see from your output

```
Map output bytes=4187027
Map output materialized bytes=519225
...
```

that you are doing compression on (at least) the intermediate map output data.  You might try rerunning your example with compression turned off; GZIP compression is notoriously taxing on your machines' processors. Maybe before you turn off compression you might consider monitoring your CPU load to verify that this is indeed your bottleneck.

I've seen excessively long job times when running clusters that are 2 or 3 nodes with GZIP compression turned on. This changes as you start adding nodes. When I scaled that cluster up to 10 nodes and reran the same job, compression had actually become highly beneficial (to the tune of about a 40% improvement on a 100GB Terasort's overall job time versus not using compression).